# Maduino (Arduino Zero) at91samd21g18 - Unable to connect to the serial port

Tags: serial, arduino-zero

I have been using this device very little but it was use to work, and it also gave me the same issue in the past, the somewhat I was able to upload again.

I tried to use the reset button, and short GRD with RST pins, but nothing helped.
The device is recognised as **Arduino MRK1000** and connected.
I also tried to specify **Arduino Zero (Native USB Port)**.
*Under Tools > Get Board* Info I get:

```
BN: Arduino MKR1000
VID 0x2341
PID: 0X804E
SN: 414C4E1[...]
```

**My issue:**
When I try to upload the sketch (even empty) it hangs forever, or some times it shows the same message shown when you unplug the device while uploading.

```
No device found on COM5
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

The serial monitor is unable to connect

```
Sketch uses 33108 bytes (12%) of program storage space. Maximum is
262144 bytes. Global variables use 3552 bytes (10%) of dynamic memory,
leaving 29216 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 32768 bytes.
No device found on COM5 Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

**Attempted resolution actions:**
I tried to use the reset button, and short GRD with RST pins, but nothing helped.
I tried multiple USB ports, different PC, different cable.

**For information about the device:**
https://github.com/Makerfabs/Maduino-Zero-4G-LTE
https://wiki.makerfabs.com/Maduino_Zero_4G_LTE.html

**Requests:**
If you could guide me, maybe I can try to "factory reset" the MCU, or maybe try to connect in a different way.
I read about the bootloaders but I don't know how they work and I don't want to try alone and make worse.
The manufacturer didn't reply to my messages,on GitHub I didn't receive any reply either, so this is one last attempt before I throw this into the bin.
If anyone can recommend al alternative board with GPS and LTE/4G connectivity would be a plus.

Comment: windoz computer? Try turning it off then on again, then plug in the Arduino.

Comment: use double reset to activate the bootloader. the led should pulsate when bootloader waits for upload

Comment: @Juraj how do I do the double reset? I tried in different machines, with different cables, it is definitely the sketch I uploaded that broke it.

Comment: press the reset button twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Juraj (thank you), **pushing the reset button twice** allowed me to upload an empty sketch and "revive" an otherwise unusable device.